# p:autoComplete - Pass More parameters

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm using JSF 2.2 with PrimeFaces 5.3 and I'm trying to work with the `p:autoComplete`

I think I'm doing some kind of syntax error, but I'm not able to find it

I've this piece of page

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="countryDropdown" value="#{myController.selectedCountryId}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{myController.countries}" var="co" itemValue="#{co.id}" itemLabel="#{msg[co.name]}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>

<p:autoComplete 
   dropdown="true" 
   value="#{myController.selectedAutocompleteId}" 
   completeMethod="#{myController.callMyAutocompleteMethod}">
      <f:attribute name="selectedCountryId"  value="#{carCountryDropdown}" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

In order to perform the auto-completion task I need the value of the "countryDropdown" also. 
Which syntax I need to use in order to retrieve inside the auto-completion method the value of the "countryDropdown" select item?

Inside the auto-completion method I can use the following code

```
UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(context).getAttributes().get("selectedCountryId");
```

but I get always null.

Can you help me?

Comment: Why not just use ajax in the 'countryDropDown' to set its value when selecting and use the bean value in the auto-completion method?

Comment: Because I will perform too much useless requests

Comment: How many? One? Two? Ok…

Comment: I don't know how many. And I'm not interested on know how many useless requests the application will do. The most important thing is that we can improve this approach. And I think is important to try(almost try) to use the best approach as possible

Comment: Devils advocate here (and strongly against premature optimization) So sending it each time the autocomplete fires and processing it is a sigificant less strain on your server?

Comment: It's not significant. It's just to discover / understand the appropriate solution. This is not a trick in order to improve the performance. But it's only to search the "best fit" solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use ajax, < p:selectOneMenu>  supports change event:

```
< p:selectOneMenu ..>
    < p:ajax event="change" listener="#{myController.subjectSelectionChanged}" />
    <!--...-->
< /p:selectOneMenu>
```

which triggers listener subjectSelectionChanged in which you can return the value of the "countryDropdown" in carCountryDropdown

Comment: Yes but if you agree with me it's not the best solution because if we change 5 times the "countryDropdown" and 1 time the autocomplete widget, I will create 6 different requests. In which way I can try to make requests only when the user change the autocomplete widget?

Comment: And the other way around? If the user does an autocomplete 8 times and the selectOneMenu 1 time it is send and processed to often… as mentioned above, premature optimization

Comment: If the user does an auto-complete 8 times, for the application is impossible to understand which requests are useless.We can set some kind of "delay" in order to avoid requests that are too much near in terms of time for example. I understand you but is not premature optimization. But I'm only trying to find the best solution. I thank you for all yours help. It's just to share with you(or find together) some appropriate solution that can be useful for all the community